# Load txt file from resources in Python

Tags: python, file-io, resources, text-files

I have .qrc file:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/files">
    <file alias='icon'>../icons/Delta.jpg</file>
    <file alias='eng'>../Languages/English.txt</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

which I compile into a Python python_rc.py file with pyrcc4. In my code I have:

```
import QtGui, python_rc
...
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(':/files/icon'), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
self.setWindowIcon(icon)
...
text = codecs.open(':/files/eng', 'r', "utf-8")
```

...icon is loaded with no problems, but for txt file I get:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: ':/files/eng'
```

So my question is: how should I load eng from python_rc? Is it possible for text files or only for pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason this code works and has no problems that I've mentioned in comments in zoumi's answer:

```
path = ":/languages/eng"
f = QtCore.QFile(path)
if f.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
    text = QtCore.QTextStream(f)
while not text.atEnd():
    line = unicode(QtCore.QString(text.readLine()))
    #do something with "line" here
f.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
fd = QtCore.QFile(":/files/eng")
if fd.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
    text = QtCore.QTextStream(fd).readAll()
    fd.close()
```

Because the txt file is in Qt resourse file so you can't use this:

```
text = codecs.open(':/files/eng', 'r', "utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. There is problem with utf-8 when I try to open, for example hungarian language: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0150' in position 0: character maps to <undefined> . I tryed this text1 = unicode(text, "utf-8"), but now I get this: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 653-655: invalid data. Can you help me? PS when I open files with text = codecs.open(pathToTxt, 'r', "utf-8") I dont have those problems, but I need it in resources...

Comment: Also, I can't iterate line by line like when it's open like this:
text = codecs.open(pathToTxt, 'r', "utf-8")
for line in text: print line

Comment: I'm sorry. I only use python3.x...So,I don't know how to deal with the python2.x's codecs error.I would suggest you to use python3.x to get rid of these encoding troubles.